# Derivation symmetrization canonical energy EM tensor

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The Lagrangian for the electromagnetic field is $\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu \nu}$. Noether's theorem yields the following canonical stress-energy tensor:
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu \nu} = -F^{\mu \lambda}\partial^\nu A_\lambda + \frac{1}{4} g^{\mu \nu}F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
This tensor can be symmetrized by adding a divergence $\partial_\lambda X^{\lambda \mu \nu}$ (where $X^{\lambda \mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric in its two first indices) so as to obtain the correct stress-energy tensor:
\begin{equation}
\bar{T}^{\mu \nu} = F^{\mu \lambda}F_\lambda^{\ \nu} + \frac{1}{4} g^{\mu \nu}F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
$X^{\lambda \mu \nu}=F^{\mu \lambda}A^\nu$ is supposed to work (http://research.physics.illinois.edu/Publications/theses/copies/Bandyopadhyay/Chapter_3.pdf) but I am not able to prove it.
\begin{equation}
\partial_\lambda X^{\lambda \mu \nu} = \partial_\lambda F^{\mu \lambda} A^\nu + F^{\mu \lambda} \partial _\lambda A^\nu
\end{equation}
The second term combines with $-F^{\mu \lambda}\partial^\nu A_\lambda$ to give $F^{\mu \lambda}F_\lambda^{\ \nu}$ but I don't know what to do with the first term. What am I missing?

There are several questions on the site related to the symmetrization of the canonical stress-energy tensor but none of them specifically answers my question.

Comment: Bienvenue ! It is stated between (3.14) and (3.15) that the equations of motion are applied.

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten that the Lagrangian above only worked for vacuum, so there was no current density...